# Bash Script will not recognize function

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to create a `bash` `script` that will allow you to specify an *AWS* account that you want to perform some actions in.

I have a variable I need to pass that refers to a file that the script will cycle through.

But the function that performs the actions isn't recognized by the `script`.

This is the `error` I get :

> ./delete_snapshots.sh
>
> What AWS Account:
>
> 12345678910
>
> Delete Snapshots in account: AWS Lab
>
> ./delete_snapshots.sh: line 14: delete_snapshots: command not found

This is the `script` :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "What AWS Account: ";
read accountnumber
declare -a arr=("12345678910" "109876543212")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  if [ "$i" -eq 12345678910 ]; then
     aws_account="AWS Lab"
     aws_key="lab"
     aws_file="aws_lab_snapshots.txt"
     echo "Delete Snapshots in account: $aws_account"
     delete_snapshots
     break
  elif [ "$i" -eq 109876543212 ]; then
     aws_account="AWS Billing"
     aws_key="bill"
     aws_file="aws_bill_snapshots.txt"
     echo "You are currently in account: $aws_account"
     delete_snapshots
     break
  else
     echo "Unkown account"
  fi
done

delete_snapshots(){
for i in $(cat $aws_file)
do
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo "deleting snapshot: $i"
  aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id=$i --profile=lab 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^An error occurred.*when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: //'
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo; echo; echo; echo; echo
  sleep 5
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo "Verify that snapshot: $i is gone:"
  aws ec2 describe-snapshots --snapshot-ids=$i --profile=lab 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^An error occurred.*when calling the DescribeSnapshots operation: //g'
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo; echo; echo; echo; echo
done
}
```

The script works now thanks for some helpful suggestions. Here's the working form of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash


delete_snapshots(){
for i in $(cat $aws_file)
do
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo "deleting snapshot: $i"
  aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id=$i --profile=$aws_key 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^An error occurred.*when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: //'
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo; echo; echo; echo; echo
  sleep 5
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo "Verify that snapshot: $i is gone:"
  aws ec2 describe-snapshots --snapshot-ids=$i --profile=$aws_key 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^An error occurred.*when calling the DescribeSnapshots operation: //g'
  echo "*****************************************************************"
  echo; echo; echo; echo; echo
done
}

echo "What AWS Account: ";
read accountnumber
declare -a arr=("123456789101" "109876543212")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  if [ "$i" -eq 123456789101 ]; then
     aws_account="AWS Lab"
     aws_key="lab"
     aws_file="source_files/aws_lab_snapshots.txt"
     echo "Delete Snapshots in account: $aws_account"
     delete_snapshots
     break
  elif [ "$i" -eq 109876543212 ]; then
     aws_account="AWS Billing"
     aws_key="bill"
     aws_file="source_files/aws_bill_snapshots.txt"
     echo "You are currently in account: $aws_account"
     delete_snapshots
     break
  else
     echo "Unkown account"
  fi
done
```

Comment: You need to define function using the `function` keyword. Also, your function should be defined first before invoking it. Bash is very particular about it.

Comment: Defining a function after you use it. Bash doesn't work this way. It reads a command and immediately executes it. It doesn't read and parse the entire script beforehand, unlike e.g. Python.

Comment: Ok. If I define the function first, how can I use the aws_key and aws_file variables in the function?

Comment: Just try using them normally. (When bash reads a function, it does *not* execute its lines as they are read)

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly!

Comment: @krishna_mee2004, the `function` keyword is **absolutely not** needed in bash -- its use makes code incompatible with the POSIX sh standard for no good reason. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete